# Accessing PHP array inside for loop

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

Why does the following code return correctly when called explicitly for 1, but not when called in a for loop?

> name: Granola price: 5.99
>   1 name: price:
>   2 name: price:

```
<?php
        echo "name: " . $data[1][p_name];
        echo " price: " . $data[1][price] . "<br />";

        for ($i = 1; $i <= count($data); $i++) {
            echo $i . " name: " . $data[i][p_name];
            echo " price: " . $data[i][price] . "<br />";
        }
?>
```

Comment: You probably want foreach instead of for.

Comment: Put array string keys in quotes (`'price'` instead of `price`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you used $data[i] rather than $data[$i].  PHP Variables start with a $.

Comment: Embarrassing... thank you.

Comment: I'm sure most of us have failed to see the forest for the trees on any number of occasions ;)

Comment: And while at it, also fix `$p_name` and `$price`.

Comment: @Niels: I'm guessing they are probably keys rather than variables.  Most kosher would be $data[$i]['p_name'] for example.  Of course PHP will resolve them (albeit marginally with less efficiency) even without the single quotes.

Comment: And while emitting an `E_NOTICE`.

Comment: Good point, and even better reason to do it right.

Comment: I really want to like PHP, but I just don't know if that will ever happen haha thanks everybody

Answer (score 1):

Because in the loop you're referencing a constant, `i`, not the variable `$i`. `$data[i]` should be `$data[$i]`.